# Rails 4 -how to write a view that displays instances in alternating format

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, cycle

I am trying to figure out how to present data in alternating format.

Below are two list items. The first one is just "li". The second has class="timeline-inverted" attached.  This CSS styles a timeline down the centre of a page and I want to display instances on each side (in alternating order).

FIRST LIST ITEM:

```
<li>
  <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="flaticon-clocks18"></i></div>
  <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s" data-wow-offset="10">
    <p class="timeline-time fontcolor-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> Aug 2010 - Nov 2012</p>
    <div class="timeline-photo timeline-bg01-01"></div>
    <div class="timeline-heading">
      <h3 class="font-accident-two-normal uppercase">Bluepixel LLC, London</h3>
      <h6 class="uppercase">Junior Designer</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

SECOND LIST ITEM:

```
<li class="timeline-inverted">
  <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="flaticon-graduation61"></i></div>
  <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.3s" data-wow-offset="10">
    <p class="timeline-time fontcolor-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> March 2013 - Jan 2014</p>
    <div class="timeline-photo timeline-bg02-01"></div>
    <div class="timeline-heading">
      <h3 class="font-accident-two-normal uppercase">Rocket Media, Berlin</h3>
      <h6 class="uppercase">Senior Designer</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

In my view, I currently have:

```
<div class="dividewhite4"></div>
<% profile.jobs.order(start_date: :desc).each do |job| %>
<ul class="timeline-vert timeline-light">
  <li>
    <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="flaticon-clocks18"></i></div>
    <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s" data-wow-offset="10">
      <p class="timeline-time fontcolor-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 
      </p>
      <div class="timeline-photo timeline-bg01-01"></div>
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h3 class="font-accident-two-normal uppercase"><%= job.company %></h3>
        <h6 class="uppercase"><%= job.title %></h6>
        <p><%= job.description %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<% end %>
<div class="dividewhite6"></div>
```

But what I want is to say that every first/third/fifth instance should in in that list format and the 2nd/4th/6th should be in the "li" format that has a class method attached to put it on the other side of the page.

Does anyone know how to do that?

**CYCLE SUGGESTION**

Having tried the cycle suggestion below, it puts each attribute into each of the two list items.  How can I adjust it so it only displays each attribute once, but in chronological order so they go in alternating list item styles?

```
<% profile.jobs.order(start_date: :desc).each do |job| %>
<ul class="timeline-vert timeline-light" class="<% cycle("odd", "even") %>">
  <li>
    <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="flaticon-clocks18"></i></div>
    <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s" data-wow-offset="10">
      <p class="timeline-time fontcolor-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 
        <% if job.current_job == true %> 
        <%= job.start_date.strftime('%B %Y') %>, continuing
        <% else %>   
        <%= job.period %>
        <% end %>   
      </p>
      <div class="timeline-photo timeline-bg01-01"></div>
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h3 class="font-accident-two-normal uppercase"><%= job.company %></h3>
        <h6 class="uppercase"><%= job.title %></h6>
        <p><%= job.description %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline-inverted">
    <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="flaticon-graduation61"></i></div>
    <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.3s" data-wow-offset="10">
      <p class="timeline-time fontcolor-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 
        <% if job.current_job == true %> 
        <%= job.start_date.strftime('%B %Y') %>, continuing
        <% else %>   
        <%= job.period %>
        <% end %> 
      </p>
      <div class="timeline-photo timeline-bg02-01"></div>
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h3 class="font-accident-two-normal uppercase"><%= job.company %></h3>
        <h6 class="uppercase"><%= job.title %></h6>
        <p><%= job.description %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<% reset_cycle%>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT. Updated answer**

```
<ul class="timeline-vert timeline-light">
  <% profile.jobs.order(start_date: :desc).each do |job| %>
  <li class="<%= cycle("", "timeline-inverted") %>">
    <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="flaticon-clocks18"></i></div>
    <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s" data-wow-offset="10">
      <p class="timeline-time fontcolor-invert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 
        <% if job.current_job == true %> 
        <%= job.start_date.strftime('%B %Y') %>, continuing
        <% else %>   
        <%= job.period %>
        <% end %>   
      </p>
      <div class="timeline-photo timeline-bg01-01"></div>
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h3 class="font-accident-two-normal uppercase"><%= job.company %></h3>
        <h6 class="uppercase"><%= job.title %></h6>
        <p><%= job.description %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways:

One is using the `cycle` helper (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle).

```
 # Alternate CSS classes for even and odd numbers...
 @items = [1,2,3,4]
 <table>
 <% @items.each do |item| %>
   <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") -%>">
     <td>item</td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
 </table>
```

and another is via CSS (https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this. Cycle seems like a handy feature... although I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I copied my latest attempt above. It's putting each item in my array into each alternative style. I'm not sure how to force it to alternate through the list items - which are styled differently.

Comment: `timeline-inverted` is your class to alternate right? What you would do is `<ul class="timeline-vert timeline-light <%= cycle('timeline-inverted', '') %>">`. Don't forget about `<%=` as it needs to output the string. And don't do double `class`, I think it overwrites one over the other.

Comment: Hmmm - i'm still getting each attribute displayed in each alternate. Thanks so much for the help and the explanations. I must be doing something wrong. Do I need to end the cycle inside the </ul> or after it? I've tried both ways but it isn't making a difference

Comment: Ah! I noticed you have `<% reset_cycle %>` at the end. Remove that, that resets the cycle that's why you always have the first value.

Comment: They're still repeating (each attribute in each list style).

Comment: Sorry I was a bit busy earlier but carefully looked at your code now. Shouldn't the `<UL>` be outside the `.each` loop and looping inside one `<li>`? I'll edit your question and add it to the end how I see it.

Comment: Thank you! That's great. I never would have figured that out... but it makes sense now that its in front of me.